# Combo Box history in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am trying to create a Combo Box (from the components list in flash cs4). I have gotten it to work with

```
import fl.accessibility.ComboBoxAccImpl; 
import fl.data.DataProvider; 
import fl.events.ComponentEvent; 

ComboBoxAccImpl.enableAccessibility();
var weapons:Array = [ 
    {label:"Sword", data:"SwordSelected"}, 
    {label:"Bow", data:"BowSelected"}, 
    {label:"Knife", data:"KnifeSelected"}];
testtxt.text = String("sword");

weaponselector.dataProvider = new DataProvider(weapons); 

weaponselector.addEventListener(ComponentEvent.ENTER, weaponsadd); 
weaponselector.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, weaponboxselecter);


function weaponboxselecter(event:Event):void
{
    if (ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data != "SwordSelected")
    {
        selectSword();
        testtxt.text = String(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.label);
    }
    else if (ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data != "BowSelected")
    {
        selectBow();
        testtxt.text = String(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.label);
    }
    else if (ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data != "KnifeSelected")
    {
        selectKnife();
        testtxt.text = String(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.label);
    }
}
```

but then i tryed to create a history if what is being clicked(selectKnife/selectBow/selectSword in the weaponboxselecter function)

```
var weaponsHistory:Array = ["Sword"];
trace(weaponsHistory);
function selectBow()
{
    var Bowadds:Bowadd = new Bowadd();
    Bowadds.x = 300
    Bowadds.y = 300
    stage.addChild(Bowadds);
    trace(weaponsHistory);
    weaponsHistory.splice(1, "Bow");
}

function selectKnife()
{
    var Knifeadds:Bowadd = new Bowadd();
    Knifeadds.x = 300
    Knifeadds.y = 300
    stage.addChild(Knifeadds);
    weaponsHistory.splice(1, "Knife");
    trace(weaponsHistory);
}

function selectSword()
{
    var Swordadds:Bowadd = new Bowadd();
    Swordadds.x = 300
    Swordadds.y = 300
    stage.addChild(Swordadds);
    weaponsHistory.splice(1, "Sword");
    trace(weaponsHistory);
}
```

but it always traces sword

any suggestions

thanks

[New Code]

```
var weaponsHistory:Array = ["Sword"];
function weaponboxselecter(event:Event):void{
if(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data != "SwordSelected"){
    selectSword();
    testtxt.text = String(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.label);
    weaponsHistory.splice(0,0,"Sword");

}else if(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data != "BowSelected"){
    selectBow();
    testtxt.text = String(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.label);
    weaponsHistory.splice(0,0,"Bow");


}else if(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data != "KnifeSelected"){
    selectKnife();
    testtxt.text = String(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.label);
    weaponsHistory.splice(0,0,"Knife");



}
[new code]
trace(weaponsHistory);// just less code
[end new code]
    }
```

this still doesn't work. I will explain it a bit better:

The Sword is first selected. Then when i click on the Bow/Knife the Sword is replaced with Bow/Knife. That way i can add and remove objects based on what was last clicked(if you have another way of doing this i am up for other options.)

What is happening is that the Sword is being traced than if i click on knife, sword is traced and if i click on bow, Sword is traced but if the click on sword or knife again than bow is traced.

thanks

[new Code]

```
function selectBow(){
    var Bowadds:Bowadd = new Bowadd();
    Bowadds.x = 300
    Bowadds.y = 300
    stage.addChild(Bowadds);
    trace(weaponsHistory);





}


function selectKnife(){
    var Knifeadds:Bowadd = new Bowadd();
    Knifeadds.x = 300
    Knifeadds.y = 300
    stage.addChild(Knifeadds);
    trace(weaponsHistory);




}

function selectSword(){
    var Swordadds:Bowadd = new Bowadd();
    Swordadds.x = 300
    Swordadds.y = 300
    stage.addChild(Swordadds);
    trace(weaponsHistory);

}


function weaponsadd(event:ComponentEvent):void { 
    var newRow:int = 0; 
    if (event.target.text == "Add") { 
        newRow = event.target.length + 1; 
            event.target.addItemAt({label:"screen" + newRow, data:"screenData" + newRow},  
            event.target.length);  
    } 
}

function weaponboxselecter(event:Event):void{
if(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data != "SwordSelected"){
    selectSword();
    testtxt.text = String(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.label);
    weaponsHistory.push("Sword");

}else if(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data != "BowSelected"){
    selectBow();
    testtxt.text = String(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.label);
    weaponsHistory.push("Bow");


}else if(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data != "KnifeSelected"){
    selectKnife();
    testtxt.text = String(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.label);
    weaponsHistory.push("Knife");



}
}
```

It all works except for the knife. It only traces sword...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [splice(...)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29) incorrectly. I'm not entirely certain what is occuring, but the proper use of splice includes a *start index*, a *delete count* and and the optional additions. Try `...splice(1,0,"...");`.

Alternatively, if you want the addition to come first in the array, `...splice(0,0,"...");` may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You should look through step-by-step at what your code is doing.

In your second code example, on the first line, you set `weaponsHistory` to `["sword"]`. So it will be sword when you trace it.

Then in your `selectKnife` and `selectSword` methods you add `"Knife"` or `"Sword"` to index `1` of your `weaponsHistory` array, then trace it.

Seems like you problem is it the `selectBow` method. Looks like you trace `weaponsHistory` before you even modify it.

Just a note; If you are trying to add an item to the end of an array you should probably use push rather than splice (use `weaponsHistory.push("Bow");` rather than `weaponsHistory.splice(1, "Bow");`)

Comment: wasn't me actually this is very helpful